# flutter: How to remove mapbox logo

Tags: flutter, mapbox

I am using [mapbox](https://pub.dev/packages/mapbox_gl) on my application, When Map is shown, the mapbox logo is shown :

[image]

How can I remove logo?

```
MapboxMap(
                  accessToken: MAPBOX_TOKEN,
                  initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                    target: controller.center.value,
                    zoom: 8.0,
                  ),
                  onMapCreated: (ctl) => controller.mapController = ctl,
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per their website

> The Mapbox logo is a small image containing the stylized word "Mapbox". It typically resides on the bottom left corner of a map. While you may move the logo to a different corner of the map, we require the Mapbox logo to appear on our maps so that Mapbox and its maps get proper credit.

So no, you should not remove the Mapbox logo. This is the same for Google maps aswell.

Comment: Mean, No way to remove that?

Comment: Well, you could use a `Stack` and add a white `Container` on top bottom of the map.

Comment: Any updates on this? or other way to hide that button?

Comment: @SpikeSpiegel nope still the same. You can look [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/getting-started/attribution/) for more details.

Comment: I believe I have to hide that by changing its position under my app bar or bottom bar of my application. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide the logo and option button from mapbox but you can do a trick.. Set the `logoViewMargins` to your comfort which will hide the logo and settings button from the screen... Its will be there but you can't see it

`logoViewMargins: const Point<num>(-100, -100),`